# QGIS Web Client printing error with some text added to template

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-web-client

I have a problem using printing. If I put a text label object (I want to add some text to the template) then pdf would never generate (it is error generating pdf shown). It only generates without any text added. My template works well with added elements like scale, image, legend. I don't know what to do to add also text.

Do you have any idea or any examples of working print layouts with some text added?

Answer (score 1):

I found the possibility to go over the problem. I used Attribute Tables with just one row which is showing text which I want to add to map.
However adding text fields to the composer layer still causes crash while trying to generate pdf with qgis-web-client. Only this method which I used is working and client can generate prints.